# Web app showing different screen at visual studio and Azure

Tags: c#, .net, azure, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

I am maintaining an app, developed by someone else who is not in the organization anymore.
And my skill with .net is very limited. (Can run and deploy the code.)

[image]

As you can see in the image, the same code and same database it works fine in visual studio, I can see the table with columns. But the deployed code in Azure is not showing the table.

Just want to check with experts here, if you see anything obvious missing here?

Just a bit of background about the above Table: It is a dynamic table, Admin can customize the table columns, width, etc.

Apologies for the silly question, but just trying if I can get a quick win by asking it here.

Cheers David

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a runtime issue, which occurs when the files in your wwwroot folder are precisely what they should be, but the site doesn't function correctly for some reason, such as a missing element, or it could be due to a change in how the page is viewed.

After you've deployed, check your Kudu Console to see if the View of the controller you're deploying has changed.

I tried reproducing the same and this is how I compared my Kudu Console.cshtml and VS Code.cshtml files.

[image]

---

[image]

---

Here is the output

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Swetha for looking into it, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran in inspect mode found some of the .js files were showing 404 error.[image]

Checked the visual studio and for some reason, those were not added to the project!!
So I had to manually include them in the project. After publishing it is now working fine.